# Vancouver with biblatex bibliography format

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

how can I get instead of 1. having [1] in the bibliography ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{ministerium,
    author = {{Bundesministerium für Familie, Senioren, Frauen und Jugend}},
    title  = {{Stief- und Patchworkfamilien in Deutschland}},
    url    = {https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/76242/1ab4cc12c386789b943fc7e12fdef6a1/monitor-familienforschung-ausgabe-31-data.pdf},
    year   = {2013},
    urldate = {2022-09-29},
    
}
 @online{essai1,
    author = {Pibasso, Achille Mbog},
   year =   {2021},
    title = {Le Cameroun s’imprègne du modèle de la microfinance allemande},
   urldate = {2022-09-29},
   month =  {2021-01-22},
    url =   {https://www.financialafrik.com/2021/01/22/le-cameroun-sempreigne-du-modele-de-la-microfinance-allemande/}
 }



\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=vancouver,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

%option 1:
%\usepackage{xurl} % <-- important
%\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional



%option 2    
% formatting of hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}



\begin{document}
%\nocite{*}

\cite{essai1} et \cite{ministerium}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}` like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=vancouver,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

%option 1:
%\usepackage{xurl} % <-- important
%\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional


\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

%option 2    
% formatting of hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}



\begin{document}
%\nocite{*}

\cite{knuth:ct} et \cite{westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you please  explain what should I do to perform such type of line command ? [link ](https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

Comment: @Johnvador I'm not sure what you mean with your comment

Comment: i mean the command '\DeclareFieldFormat*{labelnumberwidth}{[#1]}' is specific to biblatex ?

Comment: Yes, it is a biblatex macro

Comment: if I want to change the place of the field like the date at the end to the middle what should I do ?

Comment: Best things would be to ask a new question in which you show an example of how exactly the result should look like.

Comment: It is probably preferable to use `\mkbibbrackets{#1}` instead of `[#1]`. `numeric.bbx` for example has `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your suggestion!